# How do I tell or allow Blazor to "refresh" an HTML element from its bound value that hasn't changed?

Tags: blazor

When I have a one-way binding on a HTML element and accompanying binding on `onchange` that doesn't always change it, then how do I tell or allow Blazor to "refresh" that element's value from its bound value that hasn't changed?

StateHasChanged() doesn't work, presumably because Blazor detects that there has been no change.

Minimalist but absurd example (note that the real-world case is not absurd):

```cs
@page "/"
<select value="@Foo" @onchange="Update">
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
</select> 
<div>
  Value of Foo: @Foo
</div>
@code {
  private string Foo {get;set;} = "First";
  private void Update(ChangeEventArgs args) {
    return; // doesn't actually change it
  }
}
```

Thus the new value in the HTML element shows immediately on changing it, but the bound value never actually changes. [Working demo here](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/plr0d75n): how do I get the value of the drop down to remain (or change back to) "First", which is the unchanged value stored in Foo?

Comment: `note that the real-world case is not absurd.`  If so, provide it.

Comment: I'd rather provide the minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the Renderer and Diffing engine.

The value has changed in Browser DOM, but not in the Renderer DOM.  This is one of the few occasions when the two get "legitimately" out of sync in Blazor.  So when you change the value back to what it was, the Diffing engine see's no difference and thus doesn't send any updates to the Browser DOM.  You see a similar situation when building text boxes where you only allow certain input characters.

The only solution I know is to leverage the async behaviour of the Blazor UI event handler.

1. Set the value to something different - I normally use `String.Empty` 2. Yield control so the UI can do an update using `Task.Delay`
2. The UI handler calls `StateHasChanged` and updates the UI.
3. Set it to the value you want it to be.
4. The UI handler does it's final `StateHasChanged` and will update the input to the correct value.

```
@page "/"

<div>
Foo: <select value="@Foo" @onchange="Update">
  <option>(none)</option>
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
</select> 
</div>

<div>
  Value of Foo: @Foo
</div>
@code {
    private string Foo {get;set;} = "First";

    private async Task Update(ChangeEventArgs args) {
        Foo = string.Empty;
        await Task.Delay(1);
        Foo = "First";
  }
}
```

Comment: [Polite] You don't seem to have understood the question...

Comment: I've updated my answer to actually answer the question - Thanks to @enet for pointing out my error!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to give the element a `@key` that you change when you want to force a refresh. This will completely tear down and recreate the element though, so it can be costly.

```html
@page "/"

<select @key="@Forced" value="@Foo" @onchange=@( e => Update(e) )>
  <option>(none)</option>
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
</select>
```

```cs
@code {
  private string Foo {get;set;} = "First";
  private int Forced {get;set;} = 0;
  private Task Update(ChangeEventArgs args) {
    if (1 == 1){ // placeholder for other logic 
      Forced++; // doesn't actually change it
    }
    else
    {
      Foo = args.Value.ToString() ?? "(none)";
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask; 
  }
}
```

[Updated demo](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/eo7q5ld9)

Comment: Really? We must be missing something.

Comment: Like what? You see that the value has changed,  but you want to prevent it.  That is not normal.  Why not disable the control instead?

Comment: Because we don't know that the value is not allowed till the user chooses it and thus other complicated/slow code runs.  Your skepticism is appreciated, though: I agree this is a minority case and shouldn't happen too often.

Comment: Ok, but what are about your previous statement "we must be missing something" ... what do you think is being missed?

Comment: That Blazor has no way to trigger an HTML element to re-bind nor does so automatically.  Seems like such an obvious need, given that [all abstractions leak](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/).

Comment: What you are doing is breaking the automatic binding - Blazor can see that the value you bound has not changed (because you prevented it), so is correctly not sending an update to the dom. Your other option was described by Mr C above - allow the value binding to happen, then revert it back to the previous value.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your requirement, try this code, it will show selected value of Foo

```
<select value="@Foo" @onchange="@(e=> Foo=e?.Value?.ToString())">
  <option value="(none)">(none)</option>
  <option value="First">First</option>
  <option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
```